# Проблема с кодировкой куска сайта

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Есть такая беда: пхп сайт с кодировкой 1251, сам по себе отображает всё норм, но в одном месте погружается контент через jQuery с пхп файла(если его отдельно открывать, то тоже хорошо показывает, выводит пару тегов) и инфа отображается некорректо, помогите плиз!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно, где у вас и что не корректно выводит, но попробую посоветовать в файле с подгружаемом контентом (там судя по всему не используются теги html указывающие кодировку) указать кодировку через php.

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=<Используемая вами кодировка>');
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло)